# Vermögen eines Multimillionärs

Tags: meaning, noun

Nach einiger Diskussion mit einem Kollegen gibt es zwei Arten, die finanzielle Definition eines "Multimillionärs" zu bestimmen:

1. Multimillionär ist man, wenn man 1 Million EUR + min. 1 Cent besitzt, da "Multi" aus griechisch "viel" kommt, und viel auch "mehr als eins" sein kann. Somit würde der eine Cent reichen.
2. Multimillionär ist man, wenn man 2 Millionen EUR besitzt oder mehr, weil man mehrere Millionen besitzt.

Mir persönlich erscheint nur die zweite Definition als gültig. Ist das eine Frage des Geschmacks oder gibt es entscheidende Argumente für oder gegen eine der Varianten?

Danke im Voraus für erhellende Beiträge

Comment: Ich benutze die zweite Variante, wobei aber eh fraglich ist, wann man 2 Millionen "besitzt". Zählen Immobilienwerte? Aktien? Nur das Geld auf dem Konto?

Comment: Woher das Geld kommt ist egal, obs Bar, auf der Bank oder in Goldbarren unter der Matratze liegt. Die Frage ist mehr darauf bezogen, ab welcher Gesamtsumme ich mich Multimillionär nennen darf.

Comment: Danke für die interessanten Antworten. Ich bin froh, dass sich das mit meiner Meinung deckt. Da das Ganze aber (ein wenig) eine Geschmackssache ist, und der Kollege noch nicht überzeugt ist, lasse ich die Frage mal noch 1-2 Tage so stehen, damit sich allfällige Andersdenkende noch zu Wort melden können. Ansonsten werde ich die Antwort mit den meisten Upvotes akzeptieren.

Comment: Ich arbeite schon an der dritten Million (die ersten beiden sind nichts geworden...)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Wie du selbst geschrieben hast:

"Multi" kommt von griechisch "viel", was auch "mehr als eins" sein kann. 
In diesem Fall ist ein Multimillionär jemand, der "viele" Millionen besitzt, also mindestens 2.

Auch für "mehr als eine Million" wären es mindestens zwei, da man von Millionen ausgeht. Die Zählschritte dabei sind 1 Million, 2 Millionen, 3 Millionen …
Also ist "mehr als eine Million" in diesem Kontext nicht 1 Million und 1 Cent (oder mehr), sondern 2 Millionen oder mehr.

Comment: Eins, zwei, viele, und jetzt sogar eins, viele?

Comment: Möchtest du damit sagen, dass "viele" nicht "mehr als eins" bedeuted, sondern "mehr als zwei"?

Comment: "Eins, zwei, viele" ist doch der ironische Spruch, den man auf Leute anwendet, denen man unterstellen will, dass sie nicht bis drei zählen können, oder nicht? Natürlich hier nur im übertragenen Sinn auf die spezielle Aussage bezogen. Aber ich glaube, ich habe in meinem Antwortbeitrag schon ziemlich klar gemacht, was meiner Meinung und Recherche nach unter "viele" zu verstehen ist. Der eine oder andere Beleg wäre auch für die anderen Antworten nicht schlecht gewesen.

Answer (score 20):

"Multi" wird im Sinne von "mehrfach" oder "vielfach" benutzt, nicht im Sinne von "mehr als".

Da ein "[Millionär](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Million%C3%A4r)" per Definition (mindestens) *eine* Million Euro / Dollar / Geldeinheit oder äquivalent besitzt, erfüllt ein "Multimillionär" dieses Kriterium *mehrfach*, besitzt also *mehrere Millionen*. Der Kollege hat nur insofern Recht, als bereits 2 x 1 Million als "multi" gilt.

Answer (score 14):

Da wohl kein Millionär dauerhaft exakt 1.000.000,00 Euro sein Eigen nennt, gäbe es praktisch nur Multimillionäre, wenn man Definition 1 voraussetzt. Der Begriff "Millionär" wäre damit entbehrlich. Wenn der Begriff "Multimillionär" also irgendeine Unterscheidungskraft besitzen soll, muss man m.E. Definition 2 anwenden.

Comment: Prima logische Begründung durch Ausschluß!

Answer (score 8):

Wenn jemand zwei Millionen besitzt, würde ich noch lange nicht von einem Multimillionär sprechen. Der Duden führt zwar als Bedeutung auch "mehrfacher" Millionär an, aber schon "Millionär" allein ruft nicht die darauf eingeengte Vorstellung hervor, dass der Betreffende lediglich eine Million besitzen darf.

Sinnvollerweise setzt die Bezeichnung "Multimillionär" die so Bezeichneten signifikant von den Millionären ab. Auch bei Statistiken über den Vermögenszuwachs im Privateigentum gilt der Begriff für Millionenvermögen ab einem Faktor von mindestens 10. Als beliebiges Beispiel berichtet Spiegel online von einem [World Ultra Wealth Report von Wealth-X und UBS](http://www.spiegel.de/wirtschaft/reichtum-deutschland-hat-die-meisten-multimillionaere-in-europa-a-1003878.html), in dem die Grenze bei 30 Mio. US$ liegt.

Dass der Zusatz "multi" auf jeden Fall mehr bezeichnet als "zwei", ist z.B. schon aus den Paarungen "unilateral" (einseitig), "bilateral" (zweiseitig) und "multilateral" (mehr- bzw. vielseitig) abzulesen. Alle lateinischen Composita mit "multi" bezeichnen Eigenschaften, die sich aus einer Vielheit ergeben. Die lat. Adverbien "multo" und "multum" bedeuten "um Vieles", "bei Weitem", "vielmals", "oft" etc.

Der griechische Ursprung "mala", der im Lateinischen als "multus" und "melior" weiterlebt, bestärkt eine bestimmte Qualität: gern, sehr, heftig, sehr gut etc. Als direkte Referenz für "Multimillionär" kann man ihn wohl kaum heranziehen. Schon gar nicht bezeichnet das deutsche "viel" "mehr als eins", das kann man nur noch als semantisches Hijacking einstufen. Es ist mit dem griechischen "polys" verwandt (zahlreich, weit, ausgedehnt, groß etc.) und bezeichnet eine unbestimmte, große Zahl (vgl. [Grimms Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GV07578)).

Aber selbst wenn wir Bedeutung und Etymologie von "multi-", "viele" etc. außer Acht lassen, zeigt ein einfacher Rechenvorgang, warum die Gleichung "Multimillionär = ab 2 Mio." völlig sinnlos wäre. Man sollte nämlich nicht die Verdopplung um 100 % von 1 auf 2 Millionen betrachten, sondern das gesamte Potenzial des Vermögenszuwachses eines solchen "Multimillionärs", bis er zu  den Milliardären gehört: das sind 998,000.000 der jeweiligen Währungseinheit. Wenn der Millionär bis 1,99... Mio. reicht, der Multimillionär aber von 2 Mio. bis zur Milliarde, entbehrt diese spezielle Bezeichnung mit einer Spannweite von 0,2 % bis 100 % aller möglichen Millionen-Vermögensgrößen jeglicher semantischen Signifikanz. Das würde umso mehr gelten, wenn man "Millionär" als allgemeinen Überbegriff und "Multimillionär" als spezielleren Unterbegriff verstünde.

Comment: Die Argumentation ist zwar einleuchtend aber nicht zwingend. Wenn jmd. 17 Millionen hat darf man ihn sowohl Multimillionär als auch Millionär nennen. Dass der eine Begriff passt schließt den anderen nicht zwingend aus. Bei multimorbid müssen m.W. auch nur zwei Krankheiten vorhanden sein, bei einem 2dimensionalen Array darf man auch multidimensional sagen. Da der Begriff Bimillionär nicht gängig ist hilft die Betrachtung zu bilateral auch nicht weiter.

Comment: @userunknown Ok, ich hindere niemanden daran, sich in irgendeinem Ocean Club lächerlich zu machen, wenn er 2 Mio. auf der hohen Kante hat und sich als Multimillionär bezeichnet. Letztlich ist es immer eine Frage der Relation. Wenn ich sage "Im Raum waren viele Menschen versammelt, aber nach 5 Minuten verließen ihn beide wieder", wird das wohl seltsam klingen. Ein multinationaler Konzern hat normalerweise mehr als in zwei Ländern Standorte. Die Frage ist doch, welchen Sinn eine derartige semantische Erweiterung hat, und wenn schon eine Verdopplung reichte, könnte man sie auch gleich weglassen.

Comment: @Martin Schwehla: macht sich dort nicht jeder lächerlich, der sich selbst als „Multimillionär“ bezeichnet? Ich mein’, man erkennt wirklich reiche Menschen doch eher daran, dass sie nicht über ihren Reichtum sprechen…

Answer (score 0):

Der Duden hat es doch schon erklärt ("Mehrfacher Millionär"). Das bedeutet, es muss mindestens das Zweifache ("mehrfach") einer Million vorhanden sein. Man ist somit bereits mit und vor allem aber erst ab 2 Millionen Multimillionär.